# Pass flag to merge module from WiX installer?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3, merge-module

We have merge modules that will install PDB files when a certain conditional variable is true however we need this condition to be set.

Can I set this condition in the WiX installer and pass it to the merge module somehow?

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on WiX here: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=wix-users&max_rows=25&offset=18&style=nested&viewmonth=200809&viewday=26   I've found official documentation to be somewhat lacking, good luck.

Answer (score 4):

You can set installer properties in merge modules by using this format:

```
<property_name>.<module_GUID>
```

For example:

```
CONDITION_PROPERTY.32D73316_E513_43C3_99F5_381A4B5F0A78
```

In your installer you can try using a custom action to set the property used in the merge module condition.

The custom action element can look like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetMsmProperty" Return="check" Property="CONDITION_PROPERTY.32D73316_E513_43C3_99F5_381A4B5F0A78" Value="myValue" />
```

You can schedule the action after InstallExecuteSequence -> AppSearch, so you can add this InstallExecuteSequence element:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetMsmProperty" After="AppSearch">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

You can read more about wix custom actions here:

- http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm
- http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_installexecutesequence.htm

Comment: where abouts in the wxs file would I set this?

Answer (score 0):

I just typically create a subfeature to create a variation point in the installer.  You can then put a feature condition on it to control whether the components brought in by the merge modules get installed or not.   This is a lot simpler then putting a condition on each component and gives you more flexibility of whether you want to show the "debug symbols" feature to the end user or not.